# Unable to send data in headers to authorize the request in php

Tags: http-headers, angular5, angular-services

I am getting the error message in cli like :

```
Type 'Headers' has no properties in common with type 'RequestOptionsArgs'
```

. However, the code executes. The version I am using is 5, as it shows in package.json. I am unable to find a good http example, which suit my need. I want to send some parameters in headers section, and authorize it in php. Here is the service code:
user.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Customer } from './../models/customer';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
import { apiServicesURL,appServicesURL } from "../constants/globals";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

//headers : Headers ;
constructor(private http: Http) {
}

getCustomerInfoo(custId): Observable<Customer> {
    //cust.push({token : localStorage.getItem('token')}); 
    console.log(apiServicesURL + 'getCustomers');
    let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    let api_token = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
    let email = localStorage.getItem('email');
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
   // let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(apiServicesURL + 'getCustomers', JSON.stringify({ customer_id: custId, token: api_token, email: email }), headers  ).map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        return <Customer>response.json();


    });

}


}
```

Any help, appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 5 then try it this below code and write `RequestOptionsProvider` to `module.ts` file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from '@app/core/services/auth.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class DefaultRequestOptionsService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // Get the auth header from the service.
    // const authHeader = this.auth.getAuthorizationHeader();
    // Clone the request to add the new header.
    // const authReq = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', authHeader)});
    const authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json') });
    // Pass on the cloned request instead of the original request.
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }

}
export const RequestOptionsProvider = { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: DefaultRequestOptionsService, multi: true };
```

Comment: Could you be more specific on what to write on module.ts file? Should I import RequestOptionsProvider or should I import DefaultRequestOptionsService class?

Comment: you have to use in `providers: [ RequestOptionsProvider ]`.